# Running program from within bash, can't get space escaping right

Tags: macos, bash, mdns, dns-sd

I'm writing a bash script on Mac OSX 10.11 to automatically use dns-sd to "proxy" my Bonjour advertisements for AFP, SMB & some printers when I connect to my VPN.

The basic gist of my script is I declare a number of arrays to later use when I call dns-sd. The array I'm having difficulty with being:

```
SERVICE_TEXTS=(
''
''
model=TimeCapsule8,119
model=Xserve
'txtvers=1 qtotal=1 pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.brother-hbp rp=duerqxesz5090 ty=Brother\ MFC-9120CN product=\(Brother MFC-9120CN\) adminurl=http://BRN001BA9243652.local./ priority=50 usb_MFG=Brother usb_MDL=MFC-9120CN Color=T Copies=T Duplex=F PaperCustom=T Binary=T Transparent=T TBCP=F'
'txtvers=1 qtotal=1 pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.brother-hbp rp=duerqxesz5090 ty="Brother MFC-9120CN" product="(Brother MFC-9120CN)" adminurl=http://BRN001BA9243652.local./ priority=75 usb_MFG=Brother usb_MDL=MFC-9120CN Color=T Copies=T Duplex=F PaperCustom=T Binary=T Transparent=T TBCP=F'
'txtvers=1 qtotal=1 pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.brother-hbp ty="Brother MFC-9120CN" product="(Brother MFC-9120CN)" adminurl=http://BRN001BA9243652.local./ priority=25 usb_MFG=Brother usb_MDL=MFC-9120CN Color=T Copies=T Duplex=F PaperCustom=T Binary=T Transparent=F TBCP=T'
)
```

To determine whether I need to actually run dns-sd, I do:

```
ifconfig ppp0 &>/dev/null
```

Test ifconfig's return value with:

```
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then...
```

Provided ppp0 exists, I loop through the length of my array, checking to see if dns-sd is currently running, and so on.

If dns-sd instances have been running but ppp0 is now unavailable, I kill them all by PID which I save, and check again in a few minutes.

I'm confident the rest of my code is performing what I desire, so I'll jump straight to the offending line, in hope the general idea is clear enough.

```
dns-sd -P "${SERVICE_NAMES[$n]}" "${SERVICE_TYPES[$n]}" local ${SERVICE_PORTS[$n]} "${SERVICE_NAMES[$n]}.local" "${SERVICE_IPS[$n]}" ${SERVICE_TEXTS[$n]} &>/dev/null &
```

The man page for dns-sd shows this to be usage of -P, for clarity.

```
dns-sd -P <Name> <Type> <Domain> <Port> <Host> <IP> [<TXT>...]              (Proxy)
```

The problem I face is the behaviour of space characters in the last three SERVICE_TEXTS elements. Troubleshooting so far has been to do everything in the terminal to make sure I'm not missing something super obvious / going mad. Here's exactly what I type and exactly what's returned... Which works

```
$ dns-sd -P "Brother MFC-9129CN" _ipp._tcp local 631 "Brother MFC-9120CN.local" 192.168.1.2 txtvers=1 qtotal=1 pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.brother-hbp rp=duerqxesz5090 ty=Brother\ MFC-9120CN product=\(Brother\ MFC-9120CN\) adminurl=http://BRN001BA9243652.local./ priority=50 usb_MFG=Brother usb_MDL=MFC-9120CN Color=T Copies=T Duplex=F PaperCustom=T Binary=T Transparent=T TBCP=F

Registering Service Brother MFC-9129CN._ipp._tcp.local host Brother MFC-9120CN.local port 631 TXT txtvers=1 qtotal=1 pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.brother-hbp rp=duerqxesz5090 ty=Brother\ MFC-9120CN product=\(Brother\ MFC-9120CN\) adminurl=http://BRN001BA9243652.local./ priority=50 usb_MFG=Brother usb_MDL=MFC-9120CN Color=T Copies=T Duplex=F PaperCustom=T Binary=T Transparent=T TBCP=F
DATE: ---Sat 03 Oct 2015---
21:11:40.927  ...STARTING...
21:11:41.818  Got a reply for record Brother MFC-9120CN.local: Name now registered and active
21:11:41.818  Got a reply for service Brother MFC-9129CN._ipp._tcp.local.: Name now registered and active
```

When I use a variable in the command however (echo'd for clarity)... This happens

```
$ echo ${SERVICE_TEXTS[4]}
txtvers=1 qtotal=1 pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.brother-hbp rp=duerqxesz5090 ty=Brother\ MFC-9120CN product=\(Brother MFC-9120CN\) adminurl=http://BRN001BA9243652.local./ priority=50 usb_MFG=Brother usb_MDL=MFC-9120CN Color=T Copies=T Duplex=F PaperCustom=T Binary=T Transparent=T TBCP=F

$ dns-sd -P "Brother MFC-9129CN" _ipp._tcp local 631 "Brother MFC-9120CN.local" 192.168.1.2  ${SERVICE_TEXTS[4]}

Registering Service Brother MFC-9129CN._ipp._tcp.local host Brother MFC-9120CN.local port 631 TXT txtvers=1 qtotal=1 pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.brother-hbp rp=duerqxesz5090 ty=Brother\\\\ MFC-9120CN product=\(Brother MFC-9120CN\) adminurl=http://BRN001BA9243652.local./ priority=50 usb_MFG=Brother usb_MDL=MFC-9120CN Color=T Copies=T Duplex=F PaperCustom=T Binary=T Transparent=T TBCP=F
DATE: ---Sat 03 Oct 2015---
21:18:56.968  ...STARTING...
21:18:57.842  Got a reply for record Brother MFC-9120CN.local: Name now registered and active
21:18:57.842  Got a reply for service Brother MFC-9129CN._ipp._tcp.local.: Name now registered and active
```

The problem being the section of element 4 which goes

```
"...ty=Brother\ MFC..."
```

dns-sd reports this as being

```
"...ty=Brother\\\\ MFC..."
```

You'll notice when I simply type the string rather than use the variable, dns-sd reports it with one "\".

Obviously four "\" doesn't do me any good... If I remove the "\", I still don't get the desired result because dns-sd thinks I'm describing a new key. I type

```
"\\"
```

to try and get a literal "\" and from memory dns-sd still receives four.

I've also played around with single and double quotes, including surrounding the variable in the call to dns-sd in double quotes but that adds backslashes to every single space. This makes dns-sd treat the TXT string as one key with one value, where the value contains spaces. This is significantly less useful than calling it without quotes, so I gave up on investigating that further.

So basically, it seems dns-sd receives none or four "\"... And it just needs one then everything will work perfectly...

Calling dns-sd and passing ${SERVICE_TEXTS[$n]} without quotes comes very close to the desired behaviour, but can not handle space characters in the "value" of the key-value pairs.

Any guidance here would be much appreciated! I've been pouring over the bash manual, searching stack exchange and trying everything I can think of to make this work for going on 4 hours now :(

Comment: oh, I see that you have tried sngl and dbl-quoting. You say "but that adds backslahes to every single space". So I assume you're using the shell `set -x` debug facility? (That's good). I don't see the problem with '\'s on ever space unless you are quoting too much of your line, like `"arg1 arg2 arg2with spaces arg3"` when it should be quoted as `arg1 "arg2 arg2with spaces" arg3` ?  Pluse-uno for a trying to solve your own problem and a well written description of your travails. Good luck!

Comment: assuming that you're seeing the "add[ed] backslashes to ever space" because you're using `set -x`, you realize the backslashes you see (that you didn't include in your code) are the debug/trace facility's way of telling you 'you gave me a quoted string like "a b c", but to show you how we're interpreting it, we're showing you `a\ b\ c`' ... Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

So with the help of the blogger where I got the inspiration for this script, the problem is solved.

It was indeed a quoting issue, which I figured hence the seemingly endless experimentation with it, resulting in varying degrees of success.

Like shelter suggested, it was a case of dnd-sd receiving something like `"key=value key=value with spaces"` instead of `key=value key="value with spaces" key=valueWithoutSpaces`

The issue I faced was difficulty in seeing the EXACT command that would be executed from within my script, as dns-sd seemed to do some escaping of it's own too. From here, it would've been much easier to determine exactly where to focus my efforts on playing with the quoting.

So to check this, it was suggested that I use something like this

```
#FIX: by using a temporary variable we can debug the exact command that will be used including all quotes
CMD="dns-sd -P \"${SERVICE_NAMES[$n]}\" ${SERVICE_TYPES[$n]} local ${SERVICE_PORTS[$n]} \"${SERVICE_NAMES[$n]}.local\" \"${SERVICE_IPS[$n]}\" ${SERVICE_TEXTS[$n]} &>/dev/null &"
echo "DEBUG: $CMD"

# use exactly this command 
eval $CMD
PIDS[$n]=$!;
```

And the resulting SERVICE_TEXTS[4] key which worked

```
'txtvers=1 qtotal=1 pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.brother-hbp rp=duerqxesz5090 ty="Brother MFC-9120CN" product="(Brother MFC-9120CN)" adminurl=http://BRN001BA9243652.local./ priority=50 usb_MFG=Brother usb_MDL=MFC-9120CN Color=T Copies=T Duplex=F PaperCustom=T Binary=T Transparent=T TBCP=F'
```

It didn't help that dns-sd expected escaped brackets depending on what mechanism of escaping spaces you were using; if you were typing `\[space]` to escape a `value with spaces` it expected you to escape brackets too. But quoting the whole thing causes dns-sd to take care of the brackets itself...

So the message I'll be taking away from this, is the creation of a temporary variable to show the variable expansion, echoing it to guide the search for wonky quotes, before evaluating it.